# SDL Environment variables

Tags: sdl

"Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SDL_CFLAGS
and SDL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config."

Does anyone now how to set these environment variables in GNUStep for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GNUStep, but in Unix-like platforms environmental variables can be set in the shell (using your terminal), as:

For a single run of `mycommand`:

```
SDL_CFLAGS=foo SDL_LIBS=bar mycommand
```

To make it last for all commands until the terminal is closed:

```
export SDL_CFLAGS=foo
export SDL_LIBS=bar
```